# Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition - line numbers not appearing?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, line-numbers

In Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition, the numbers no longer appear next to the lines.  I've looked in the settings and I can't find anything.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This setting is under `Text Editor -> All Languages -> General`, check the `Line Numbers` option.

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @Nate, LOL, the first time I had to change it, took me some time to find it also!

Comment: I've just been having the same issue as the OP, and I couldn't see nearly as many options as you in my version of VSEE 2008. Turns out that I have an extra checkbox at the bottom of the options dialog labelled 'Show all settings' (probably added as an update to VSEE after your answer), which I hadn't spotted.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition:

Tools -> Options -> Line Numbers (checkbox)